# Verify $\mathbf{J}=\sigma \mathbf{f}$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction

Prove that $\displaystyle\frac{\mathbf{J}}{\mathbf{f}}$ is a constant for a given material. ($\mathbf{J}$ is the volume current density and $\mathbf{f}$ is the force per unit charge.)

Comment: Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this page in the site help](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more on what topics you can ask about here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say there is a damping force acting on electrons
$$\vec{f}_d=-b\vec{v}$$
Then the equations of motion become
$$-e\vec{E}-b\vec{v}=m\vec{a}$$
Which has the steady state solution
$$\vec{v}=-\frac{e\vec{E}}{b}$$
Which yields the current
$$\vec{J}=-ne\vec{v}=\frac{ne^2}{b}\vec{E}$$

You should be able to generalize this answer for the case of multiple charge carriers.

Comment: Please do not post answers to homework questions. Thanks :-)

Comment: Ohkayyy? This one was the whole problem. But what if someone asked for "help" not solution?

Comment: If you post even a partial answer to a homework question you encourage people to ask homework questions. The end result is a flood of homework questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the equations for the current density $J=nqv$ and the equation for force on an electron $f=eq$ you find that $\sigma=\frac{nv}{e}$. You can then sit and play with other equations for $v$ and you'll find that $\sigma=1/\rho$ which is a constant for different metals.

Comment: Please do not post answers to homework questions. Thanks :-)